# How to do stacked barplots and avoid error bars being hidden in Plotly

Tags: plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

I am trying to do stacked bars plots with symmetric error bars in between the two bars, however, the error bars become hidden by the second instance of go.Bar (Example below).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
x_values = ['A','B','C','D','E']
y1_values = [0.527, 0.519, 0.497, 0.458, 0.445]
y2_values = [0.473, 0.481, 0.503, 0.542, 0.555]
y_errors = [0.05, 0.065, 0.158, 0.07, 0.056]


fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='NAME1', x=x_values, y=y1_values, error_y=dict(type="data", array=y_errors)),
    go.Bar(name='NAME2', x=x_values, y=y2_values)
])
# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

[image: stacked barplot with errorbars hidden]

I could not find a solution to this in the documentation. Is there a way to alter the order of plot elements to force the error bar to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around this by plotting the `NAME2` bars first, followed by the `NAME1` bars – you would need to set the [base](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#customizing-individual-bar-base) of the NAME2 bars to be the `y1_values` of the NAME1 bars (so that the NAME2 bars start from where the NAME1 bars will be), then set the base of the NAME1 bars to be 0 to ensure they start from y=0.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
x_values = ['A','B','C','D','E']
y1_values = [0.527, 0.519, 0.497, 0.458, 0.445]
y2_values = [0.473, 0.481, 0.503, 0.542, 0.555]
y_errors = [0.05, 0.065, 0.158, 0.07, 0.056]


fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='NAME2', x=x_values, y=y2_values, base=y1_values),
    go.Bar(name='NAME1', x=x_values, y=y1_values, error_y=dict(type="data", array=y_errors), base=[0]*5)
])

# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it `base=[0]*5` and how does that work for 3 or more stacks?

Comment: @hans actually `base=[0]*5` isn't necessary as the last set of bars to be plotted will start from 0 by default, but I wanted the arguments for go.Bar to be consistent. `base=y1_values` is necessary as we need the NAME2 bars to start from where NAME1 bars leave off. And in the same way, if you have 3 or more bars, you would need to specify the base for every set of bars below that one. so if you had `NAME3` on top of `NAME2` and `NAME1` then you would pass the sum of the y1_values and y2_values to the base argument for NAME3

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried `base=y2_values` for `NAME3` `fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='NAME3', x=x_values, y=y3_values, error_y=dict(type="data", array=y1_errors), base=y2_values)`
     but it does not work correctly?

Comment: Just figured I have to write `base=[sum(x) for x in zip(y1_values, y2_values)]` for `NAME3` to make it work - thanks again.