# Control the distance between stacked bars plotly

Tags: python, plotly, stacked-bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

Is there a means to control the distance between the stacked bars in the example below, i.e. between the “cat” and “dog” (black arrow) and between “10 minutes” and “30 minutes” (yellow arrow)?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
x = [
    ["10 minutes", "10 minutes", "30 minutes", "30 minutes", "60 minutes", "60 minutes"],
    ["Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog"]
]
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_bar(x=x,y=[1,2,3,4,5,6], name="increase")
fig.add_bar(x=x,y=[9,8,7,6,5,4], name="decrease")
fig.add_bar(x=x,y=[5,5,5,5,5,5], name="unchanged")

fig.update_layout(barmode="stack", showlegend=True, template='plotly',
                  #bargap=0.3,
                  bargroupgap=0.2,
                  #height=500,
                  #width=1000,
                 )
fig.update_yaxes(ticks='outside',
                 dtick=2,
                 ticklen=10,
                 linewidth=1,
                 linecolor="black",
                 tickfont=dict(size=20)
                )
fig.update_xaxes(ticks="", tickfont=dict(size=12),                 
                )
fig.show()
```

gives

[image: Generated plot from code]

Comment: as with a lot of plotly questions on SO, this will likely need to be solved with some sort of workaround. i would start with trying to place the bars by using actual x values, and then replace the ticks with the intended category like Cat and Dog. i'll circle back to this when i have time later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Derek O Thanks for your suggestions that got me going, in particular this one here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75951042/14672356

Now the stacked bar plot is with error bars and time via annotations.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

y1_values=[5,4,4,5,6,5]
y2_values=[9,8,7,6,5,4]
y3_values=[4,6,7,7,7,9]

y1_errors = [0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7, 0.5, 0.8]
y2_errors = [0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5]
y3_errors = [0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4]

fig = go.Figure()
#config = dict({'scrollZoom': True})


# Bars for increase with error bars
fig.add_bar(x=[1,1.5,2.2,2.7,3.4,3.9],y=y3_values, name="Increase", marker_color='#FF6692',
            error_y=dict(type="data", array=y3_errors, thickness=2, width=10),
            base=[sum(x) for x in zip(y1_values, y2_values)]
           )

# Bars for decrease with error bars
fig.add_bar(x=[1,1.5,2.2,2.7,3.4,3.9],y=y2_values, name="Decrease", marker_color='#19D3F3',
            error_y=dict(type="data", array=y2_errors, thickness=2, width=10),
            base=y1_values
           )

# Bars for unchanged with error bars
fig.add_bar(x=[1,1.5,2.2,2.7,3.4,3.9],y=y1_values, name="Unchanged", marker_color='#00CC96',
            error_y=dict(type="data", array=y1_errors, thickness=2, width=10),
            base=[0]*6
           )

# Annotation for bar1 and bar2
fig.add_annotation(text="10 minutes",
                  xref="paper", yref="paper",
                  x=0.07, y=-0.18,
                  showarrow=False,
                  font_size=20
                  )

# Annotation for bar3 and bar4
fig.add_annotation(text="30 minutes",
                  xref="paper", yref="paper",
                  x=0.5, y=-0.18,
                  showarrow=False,
                  font_size=20
                  )

# Annotation for bar5 and bar6
fig.add_annotation(text="60 minutes",
                  xref="paper", yref="paper",
                  x=0.93, y=-0.18,
                  showarrow=False,
                  font_size=20
                  )

# Layout
fig.update_layout(barmode="stack", showlegend=True, template='plotly_white',
                  height=700,
                  width=1000,
                  legend=dict(title='', orientation="h", traceorder='normal', x=0.46, y=1.05,
                  bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', bordercolor='rgba(0,0,0,1)', borderwidth=0,
                  font_size=20
                             )
                 )

fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, showgrid=False, linewidth=0.5, linecolor='black',
                 title='<b>Percent</b>', titlefont=dict(size=24), title_standoff=30,
                 ticks='outside',
                 dtick=2,
                 ticklen=10,
                 tickfont=dict(size=20),
                 range=[0,20]
                )

fig.update_xaxes(title='', tickvals=[1,1.5,2.2,2.7,3.4,3.9],
                           ticktext=["<b>Cat</b><br>n = 15", "<b>Dog</b><br>n = 15",
                                     "<b>Cat</b><br>n = 15", "<b>Dog</b><br>n = 15",
                                     "<b>Cat</b><br>n = 15", "<b>Dog</b><br>n = 15"],
                           ticks="", tickfont_size=20, linecolor="black", linewidth=1
                ) 

fig.show()
```

[image: Stacked bar plot with error bars and annotations]